# How can I take average of second column for degenerate values of first column in c++/python or using any other linux command?

Tags: python, c++, c, linux, physics

I have a collection of data in a text file arranged in two columns. What I want is to calculate the average value for repeating numbers in the first column. e.g. for the first three rows take one average of the second column and so on. I will be grateful for any help you can provide.

0.628319    0.123401

0.628319    0.23044

0.628319    4.57734

0.888577    0.390783

1.40496 0.110672

1.40496 0.239377

1.40496 0.248376

1.40496 0.751108

1.40496 0.971678

1.40496 1.36865

Comment: You are not supposed to ask about your assignments here. Consider reading [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the data in an Excel file and read it into a Pandas DataFrame. Compute the mean of the second column grouped by the first column.

```
import pandas as pd


# header=None because there are no column headers in my XLSX file
# Column names will be integers: 0 and 1
data = pd.read_excel("physics.xlsx", header=None, engine="openpyxl")

# What does "grouped means" mean?: Sort column 1 values by column 0 value and take mean of each column-1 group
grp_means = data.groupby(0).mean()
print(grp_means)
```

Comment: Thanks Kaley, It worked for csv file as well.